# Logstash parse error CISCOTIMESTAMP Debugger checks OK

Tags: logstash, grok, logstash-forwarder

Have the following logstash conf file:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "TACACS_log" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:JsonTimestamp} %{IP:LogonTo} \s* %{USERNAME:User} \s* %{WORD:Port} \s* %{IP:LogonFrom} %{DATA} cmd=%{GREEDYDATA:command}" }
      match => { "message" => "%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:JsonTimestamp} %{IP:LogonTo} \s* %{USERNAME:User} %{WORD:Port} %{DATA} cmd=%{GREEDYDATA:command}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{LogonTo}" ]
    }
    date {
          match => [ "CISCOTIMESTAMP", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

The logs are coming in through logstash forwarder and the CISCOTIMESTAMP does not match.  Example log file:

Jun  11 11:32:38 192.168.2.49    user        tty1    10.1.250.5      stop    task_id=176     timezone=EDT    service=shell   start_time=1434036772   priv-lvl=15     cmd=show running-config

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the format of the log entry which you can see in the _message field: {"message":"Jun  2 14:43:24\t192.168.2.53\tadmintest\ttty1\t10.1.250.6\tstop\ttask_id=133\ttimezone=EDT\tservice=shell\tstart_time=1433270604\tpriv-lvl=15\tcmd=logging trap warnings ","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2015-06-12T10:14:30.493Z","type":"TACACS_log","host":"ELK","path":"/tmp/tac_plus_acct.log","JsonTimestamp":"Jun  2 14:43:24","LogonTo":"192.168.2.53","User":"admintest","Port":"tty1","LogonFrom":"10.1.250.6","command":"logging trap warnings "}

Several of the fields are tab separated, but not all.  The statement that worked is:

match => { "message" => "%{CISCOTIMESTAMP:JsonTimestamp}\s*%{IP:LogonTo}\s*%{USERNAME:User}\s*%{WORD:Port}\s*%{IP:LogonFrom}%{GREEDYDATA}cmd=%{GREEDYDATA:command}" }